# Pretty-print Lisp using Python

Tags: python, lisp, pretty-print, s-expression

Is there a way to pretty-print Lisp-style code string (in other words, a bunch of balanced parentheses and text within) in Python without re-inventing a wheel?

Comment: IS the code-string a constant, or is it computed? Tell us more about it...

Comment: It is a parse tree, so it is computed

Comment: Have you tried the `pprint` module?  The examples in the docs seem to indicate that it might do just what you want.  (I'm assuming you've got it as an S-expression, as indicated in the question, not as a tree, as your comment seems to say.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

I think a reasonable approach, if you can, is to generate Python lists or custom objects instead of strings and use the [pprint](https://pymotw.com/2/pprint/) module, as suggested by @saulspatz.

#### Long answer

The whole question look like an instance of an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why? because you are using *Python* (why not Lisp?) to manipulate *strings* (why not data-structures?) representing generated *Lisp-style* code, where *Lisp-style* is defined as "a bunch of parentheses and text within".
To the question "how to pretty-print?", I would thus respond ["I wouldn't start from here!"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WouldntStartFromHere).
The best way to not reinvent the wheel in your case, apart from using existing wheels, is to stick to a simple output format.

But first of all all, *why* do you need to pretty-print? who will look at the resulting code?

Depending on the exact Lisp dialect you are using and the intended usage of the code, you could format your code very differently. Think about newlines, indentation and maximum width of your text, for example.         The [Common Lisp pretty-printer](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/22_b.htm) is particulary evolved and I doubt you want to have the same level of configurability.
    If you used Lisp, a simple call to `pprint` would solve your problem, but you are using Python, so stick with the most reasonable output for the moment because pretty-printing is a can of worms.

If your code is intended for human readers, please:

- don't put closing parenthesis on their own lines
- don't vertically align open and close parenthesis
- don't add spaces between opening parenthesis

This is ugly:

```
 ( * ( + 3 x )
     (f 
        x
        y
     )
 )
```

This is better:

```
(* (+ 3 x)
   (f x y))
```

Or simply:

```
(* (+ 3 x) (f x y))
```

[See here](http://people.ace.ed.ac.uk/staff/medward2/class/moz/cm/doc/contrib/lispstyle.html) for more details.

But before printing, you have to parse your input string and make sure it is well-formed. Maybe you are sure it is well-formed, due to how you generate your forms, but I'd argue that the printer should ignore that and not make too many assumptions. If you passed the pretty-printer an AST represented by Python objects instead of just strings, this would be easier, as suggested in comments. You could build a data-structure or custom classes and use the [pprint](https://pymotw.com/2/pprint/) (python) module. That, as said above, seems to be the way to go in your case, if you can change how you generate your Lisp-style code.

With strings, you are supposed to handle any possible input and reject invalid ones.
This means checking that parenthesis and quotes are balanced (beware of escape characters), etc.
Actually, you don't *need* to really build an intermediate tree for printing (though it would probably help for *other* parts of your program), because Lisp-style code is made of forms that are easily nested and use a prefix notation: you can scan your input string from left-to-right and print as required when seeing parenthesis (open parenthesis: recurse; close parenthesis, return from recursion). When you first encounter an unescaped double-quote `"`, read until the next one `"`, ... 
This, coupled with a simple printing method, could be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: OP said "_It is a parse tree, so it is computed_", which probably means it is a tree dump from [ANTLR4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) , which is literally a lot of parens, rule names, and token values, all in a single line.  So they're probably not a Lisp user, just someone stuck with an S-expr-like string that needs help being even vaguely human-readable.  Which is exactly how I wound up here :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method would be to use triple quotations. If you say:

```
print """
    (((This is some lisp code))) """
```

It should work. 
You can format your code any way you like within the triple quotes and it will come out the way you want it to.

Best of luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for reply, but the question is about runtime generated strings.

Comment: @MaxMalysh when I put my answer, the discussion in your comments section had not happened yet. i thought you were just printing formatted lisp code.

Answer (score 0):

I made this rudimentary pretty printer once for prettifying CLIPS, which is based on Lisp. Might help:

```
def clips_pprint(clips_str: str) -> str:
    """Pretty-prints a CLIPS string.

    Indents a CLIPS string for easier visual confirmation during development
    and verification.
    Assumes the CLIPS string is valid CLIPS, i.e. braces are paired.
    """
    LB = "("
    RB = ")"
    TAB = " " * 4
    formatted_clips_str = ""
    tab_count = 0
    for c in clips_str:
        if c == LB:
            formatted_clips_str += os.linesep
            for _i in range(tab_count):
                formatted_clips_str += TAB

            tab_count += 1
        elif c == RB:
            tab_count -= 1
        formatted_clips_str += c

    return formatted_clips_str.strip()
```